# Hilbert space of real measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a Hilbert space of real measurable functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $$\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{1/2} < \infty.$$ I want to show that if $f$ in the Hilbert space satisfies $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0$ whenever $0\le a < b\le 1$, then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Can use the fact that step functions are dense in $^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely one way to go (also, you probably meant "then $f=0$ almost everywhere").

Comment: Alright, thanks. Thanks for the correction.